# Showing elements of an array of multiple types

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an array with the following structure:

```
{int, String, String, int}
```

I want to insert this array into another array like this:

```
{int, String, String, int}, {int, String, String, int}, ... and so on.
```

I have already tried this:

```
Object[] vector = new Object[100];

public void inserare(int poz, int nr, String nume, String prenume, int nota){

    Object[] aux = new Object[4];
    aux[0] = new Integer(nr);
    aux[1] = new String(nume);
    aux[2] = new String(prenume);
    aux[3] = new Integer(nota);

    vector[poz] = aux;

}

public void afisareLista(){

    for(int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++){
        System.out.println(vector[i]);
    }
}
```

Aux is inserted, but when I want to print all the elements of main array, all I get is something like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@15db9742
```

Any help for display correctly the elements is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an object to `System.out.println()` results to the invocation of the `toString()` method on the passed instance. This is an `Object` and `Object`'s `toString()` returns the address of the object and not a `String` containing the field names with their values.

To address this problem :

Either create and use a custom class to contain these 4 fields and populate your array with instances of this class.
Then override `toString()` in this class to return the expected String.

Or else don't rely on `toString()` but create a utility method to return a "printable" String of the object and invoke it in the argument of the `println()` method :

```
System.out.println(renderMessage(vector[i]));
...
public String renderMessage(Object[] obj){
    return "nr=" + obj[0]+ 
    "nume=" + obj[1]+
    "prenume=" + obj[2]+
    "nota=" + obj[3];
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dont do this. Build a class around your int, String, String, int and give them speaking names. Then you can put objects of this class in your array/vector and do not loose any compile type safety.